# Onclick Button only works once. Div Slider scrollIntoView

Tags: javascript

I made a slider, but I am coming up with a problem on the javascript side of things. When I use the navigation buttons I made it will work one time, but after the first initial clicks on the buttons i get a "Uncaught TypeError"

[Website](https://printer33.com)

Tried to recreate it in jfiddle for you guys, but was unsuccessful, but here's the jfiddle so you can mess with the code.

[Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rvg8fhmj/)

*PLEASE NOTE*

The reason I am using `scrollIntoView` is because all of my elements have a dynamic width (vw, vh, %), and I do not have the coding knowledge in java script to code that correctly.

```
            function pageonerby() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("hometwo");
            elem.scrollIntoView(top);
            if (elem.scrollIntoView = true) {
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }
        }

        function pagetwoer() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("homethree");
            elem.scrollIntoView();
            if (elem.scrollIntoView = true) {
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }
        }

        function pagethreeer() {
            var elem = document.getElementById("homeone");
            elem.scrollIntoView();
            if (elem.scrollIntoView = true) {
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is `if (elem.scrollIntoView = true)` supposed to do?

Comment: without it the page scrolls down a bit for some reason, it is to stop page from scrolling down. not sure if i need it or if it is correct, but it did the job.

Comment: That's... not what it does. It also causes the problem.

Comment: oh  i feel stupid

Answer (score 0):

```
            function pageonerby() { 
            var elem = document.getElementById("hometwo"); 
            elem.scrollIntoView();
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
            }
```

it's fixed.

Comment: are you sure? $('input[name=canttouchthis][value=null]').propRemove("checked"); where propRemove is not a function, would you mean the JQuery .removeProp ?